# Looping with SQL and Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a loop with Python and imported SQL data. Right now I can run a loop for any hardcoded value, however I'm getting an error when adding in the variable i. Below is my current code:

```
start = %sql SELECT * FROM streets
end = %sql SELECT * FROM streets

#path.keys
# [u'id', u'value1', u'value2', u'value3', u'value4']

for i in start:
    print start[3][4]
```

This will print out a repeating value of what is in value4 on row 3. What I'm trying to do is rewrite the the loop so that it will render the value of row i. For example

```
for i in start:
    print start[i][4]
```

However this gives me an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-215-bc2196cf4539> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for i in start:
----> 7     print start[i][4]
      8 

/Users/xxxxx/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql/run.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    136             result = [row for row in self if row[0] == key]
    137             if not result:
--> 138                 raise KeyError(key)
    139             if len(result) > 1:
    140                 raise KeyError('%d results for "%s"' % (len(result), key))
```

Any thoughts on how to rewrite this to pull in i and render the value row by row?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Start is a list, this would work:

```
for i in range(len(start)):
    print start[i]
```

To find out what `start` is and how to handle it, you can do `type(start))`. If it's some sort of SQL cursor, it wouldn't have a length property, but then you should be able to do:

```
for i in start:
    print i
```